# How do you trigger an animation inside an SVG <use> element?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I have created a simple SVG animation that is triggered by a click on the SVG element. I would like to reuse this animated element multiple times, and am hoping to avoid repeating the definition every time. However, when I create the element inside a `<defs>` tag and then implement it with a `<use>` tag, I cannot access the animations from outside.

Below is an example of the same animated element both standing on its own (yellow) and implemented as a `<use>` element (orange and red). The only animation that works is the yellow one.

I've included repeating animations inside the SVG `g`roup defined inside the `<defs>` section, to show that animations do work.

Is there a way to trigger an animation inside a `<use>` element from outside? Or is there another way to create a 2-state animation inside a re-used element?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1epsL8h/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
    g#yellow {
      fill:#cc9;
      color: #993;
    }
    use#orange {
      fill: #ca8;
      color: #963;
    }
    use#red {
      fill:#c99;
      color:#933;
    }
  </style> 
</head>

<body>
<svg width="360" height="120" 
     viewPort="0 0 120 360" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<defs>
  <g
    id="door"
    width="120"
    height="120" 
    viewPort="0 0 120 120">

    <rect width="120" height="120" class="wall"></rect>
    <rect
      x="30"
      y="20"
      width="60"
      height="100"
      fill="#000"
      opacity="0.7"></rect>

    <polygon class="door"
      points="
  30,120
  90,120
  90,20
  30,20"
      fill="currentColor">
      <animate
        class="open"
        attributeName="points"
        dur="500ms"
        to="
  100,120
  90,120
  90,20
  100,10"
      begin="indefinite" 
      fill="freeze" />
      <animate
        class="shut"
        attributeName="points"
        dur="500ms"
        to="
  30,120
  90,120
  90,20
  30,20"
      begin="indefinite" 
      fill="freeze" />
     <animate
      attributeName="opacity"
      values="0.5;1;0.5" dur="2s"
      repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </polygon>
  </g>
</defs> 

  <use x="240" y="0" xlink:href="#door" id="red"/>
  <use x="120" y="0" xlink:href="#door" id="orange"/>
  <g xlink:href="#door" id="yellow"
    id="door"
    width="120"
    height="120" 
    viewPort="0 0 120 120">

    <rect width="120" height="120" class="wall"></rect>
    <rect
      x="30"
      y="20"
      width="60"
      height="100"
      fill="#000"
      opacity="0.7"></rect>

    <polygon class="door"
      points="
  30,120
  90,120
  90,20
  30,20"
      fill="currentColor">
      <animate
        class="open"
        attributeName="points"
        dur="500ms"
        to="
  100,120
  90,120
  90,20
  100,10"
      begin="indefinite" 
      fill="freeze" />
      <animate
        class="shut"
        attributeName="points"
        dur="500ms"
        to="
  30,120
  90,120
  90,20
  30,20"
      begin="indefinite" 
      fill="freeze" />
    </polygon>
  </g>
</svg>

<script>
;(function () {
  document.body.onclick = function(event) {
    var target = event.target
    var animation

    while (target && target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "g") {
      target = target.parentNode
    }

    if (!target) {
      return
    }

    if (target.classList.contains("open")) {
      target.classList.remove("open")
      animation=document.querySelector("#"+target.id+" animate.shut")
    } else {
      target.classList.add("open");
      animation=document.querySelector("#"+target.id+" animate.open")
    }

    animation.beginElement()
  }
})()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

EDIT: I've tried an alternative approach, where I define several different `g` elements:

- one with no animation
- one with an opening animation
- one with a closing animation

I use JavaScript to swap the `href` of `<use>`element to the appropriate `g` element.

Swapping the elements fails to play the animation, with different effects in different browsers. In Chrome and Firefox, the new elements appear immediately in the post-animation state. In Apple Safari, they appear in their pre-animation state.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xocxk8hc/)

Comment: CSS animation within `<use>` elements doesn't really work in Firefox, it's a known issue.