# Animation on SVG <use> does not work in FireFox & Safari

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I have a transition animation I want to trigger on the width of an SVG element inside a group element. The animation only seems to work on the Chrome browser.

```html
<!-- works -->
<svg width="400" height="100">
  <rect id="rect-1" width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>

<!-- only works in Chrome -->
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <defs>
    <g id="my-rect">
      <rect id="rect-2" width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
    </g>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#my-rect" y="0"/>
  <use xlink:href="#my-rect" y="110"/>
</svg>
```

```css
.grow {
  -webkit-transition: 1.5s;
  -moz-transition: 1.5s;
  -o-transition: 1.5s;
  transition: 3s;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```js
(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const rect1 = document.getElementById('rect-1');
    rect1.classList.add('grow');

    const rect2 = document.getElementById('rect-2');
    rect2.classList.add('grow');
  }, 1000);
})();
```

To reproduce open this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynnckth/a8hp2cbo/3/) in Safari or Firefox.
You will see that the transition of the second rectangle does not work properly.

Is there any workaround to get the transition animation working for a specific element inside the SVG group?

Comment: Just remove the `use`, `defs` if you really don't need them, just like @mahan mentioned.

Comment: Thanks but this is no option as mentioned in my comment to @mahan's answer. I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarising, a workaround is to fall back to SMIL SVG animations instead of using CSS.

See the adapted [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynnckth/a8hp2cbo/17/) to my original question.

```html
<svg width="400" height="100">
  <rect id="rect-1" width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>

<svg width="400" height="400">
  <defs>
    <g id="my-rect">
      <rect id="g-rect" width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
    </g>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#my-rect" y="0"/>
  <use xlink:href="#my-rect" y="110"/>
</svg>
```

```js
(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const rect1 = document.getElementById('rect-1');
    rect1.classList.add('grow');

    const groupRect = document.getElementById('g-rect');

    const growAnimation = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'animate')
    growAnimation.setAttribute('attributeName', 'width');
    growAnimation.setAttribute('from', '400');
    growAnimation.setAttribute('to', '10');
    growAnimation.setAttribute('dur', '3s');
    growAnimation.setAttribute('fill', 'freeze');
    growAnimation.setAttribute('begin', 'indefinite');
    groupRect.appendChild(growAnimation);

    growAnimation.beginElement();
  }, 1000);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

#### use:

> The  element takes nodes from within the SVG document, and
>   duplicates them somewhere else. - [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use)

So It is unncesssery to use `use` since you do not duplicate it.

```js
(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const rect1 = document.getElementById('rect-1');
    rect1.classList.add('grow');

    const rect2 = document.getElementById('rect-2');
    rect2.classList.add('grow');

  }, 1000);
})();
```

```css
.grow {
  -webkit-transition: 1.5s;
  -moz-transition: 1.5s;
  -o-transition: 1.5s;
  transition: width 3s;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- works -->
<svg width="400" height="100">
  <rect id="rect-1" width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>

<svg width="400" height="100">
  <rect id="rect-2" width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
```

#### Update 1

Even SVG `<animate>` does not work in FireFox when the element is duplicated. Though if not used inside the refrensed element. This is a known issue.  There are multiple unanswered question on stackoverflow, for instance [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160438/how-do-you-trigger-an-animation-inside-an-svg-use-element).

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use -->

<svg viewBox="0 0 30 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke="blue"/>
  <use href="#myCircle" x="10" fill="blue"/>
  <use href="#myCircle" x="20" fill="white" stroke="red"/>
  <!--
stroke="red" will be ignored here, as stroke was already set on myCircle. 
Most attributes (except for x, y, width, height and (xlink:)href)
do not override those set in the ancestor.
That's why the circles have different x positions, but the same stroke value.
  -->
  
      <animate 
           xlink:href="#myCircle"
           attributeName="r"
           from="4"
           to="2" 
           dur="5s"
           begin="0s"
           repeatCount="1"
           fill="freeze" 
           id="circ-anim"/>
           
           
</svg>
```

#### Update 2

> Animations on a referenced element will cause the instances to also be animated. [use - w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#UseElement)

Per documentation, if you animate the refrenced element (`myCircle), all the duplicate of it should be aniamted too. So I guess, it is a bug that it does not work in Firefox & Safari.

## Update 3 - workaround

Use svg `<animate>` tag and enclose it in `<rect>`.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <defs>
    <g id="my-rect">
      <rect id="rect-2" width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
        <animate 
                 attributeName="width"
                 from="400"
                 to="10" 
                 dur="3s"
                 begin="1s"
                 repeatCount="1"
                 fill="freeze" 
                 id="rect-2"/>

      </rect>
    </g>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#my-rect" y="0"/>
  <use xlink:href="#my-rect" y="110"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ah crap and then someone who actually looked at the whole svg comes along and probably nails it :D +1

Comment: I was about to post this answer!

Comment: Thanks @mahan. However, the code from my question is a simplified version of a use case where I actually need to duplicate my group and apply the animation to all instances of my defined group. Therefore, I need a workaround for the usage with groups as described in the question.

Comment: @Ynnckth Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about nesting the animate tag inside circle?

```html
<svg width="400" height="350">
    <rect id="my-rect" width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
        <animate 
               attributeName="width"
               from="0"
               to="400" 
               dur="5s"
               begin="0s"
               repeatCount="1"
               fill="freeze" 
               id="rect-anim"/>
    </rect>

    <use xlink:href="#my-rect" y="110"/>
    <use xlink:href="#my-rect" y="220"/>
     
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks @Miller Cy Chan. Using SVG SMIL animations is indeed a valid fall back. I added an answer to my question including triggering the animation dynamically from the JS code.